# DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window' error when using Metamask and truffle Ganache

Tags: truffle, metamask, ganache

I faced `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException` error like below when I was developing Nuxt web app with Metamask(chrome) and truffle Ganache.

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': function (error, response) {
              _this2.removeAllListeners(payload.id);
              if (!error) {
 ...<omitted>... } could not be cloned.
```

What I tried to do is send transactions to local blockchain(Ganache).

```js
    async sendTransaction(obj) {
      const web3 = await getWeb3();
      // get account
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      const roomFactory = await getRoomFactory();

      // *ERROR OCCURS HERE*
      const result = await roomFactory.methods
        .createNewRoom(obj._roomId)
        .send({ from: accounts[0] });
      console.log("result", result);
    },
```

function `getWeb3()` and `getRoomFactory()` are following:

```js
// getWeb()

const getWeb3 = () =>
  new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    // Modern dapp browsers...
    if (window.ethereum) {
      const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
      try {
        // Request account access if needed
        await window.ethereum.enable();
        // Acccounts now exposed
        resolve(web3);
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    }
    // Legacy dapp browsers...
    else if (window.web3) {
      try {
        // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider.
        const web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
        console.log("Injected web3 detected.");
        resolve(web3);
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    }
    // Fallback to localhost; use dev console port by default...
    else {
      try {
        const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
          "http://127.0.0.1:8545"
        );
        const web3 = new Web3(provider);
        console.log("No web3 instance injected, using Local web3.");
        resolve(web3);
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    }
  });
```

```js
import getWeb3 from "~/plugins/web3.js";
import RoomFactory from "./build/contracts/RoomFactory.json"; // which is build by truffle

const getRoomFactory = async () => {
  const web3 = await getWeb3();

  const abi = RoomFactory.abi;
  const networks = RoomFactory.networks["5781"];
  return web3.eth.Contract(abi, networks.address);
};
```

**What I can do:**

- get accounts (`web3.eth.getAccounts()`) from metamask provider
- get balance (`web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0])`)

**What I cannot do:**

- send transaction to other contracts　(`Mycontract.methods.myfunction().send()`)
- call (`Mycontract.methods.myfunction().call()`)

[image: screenshot_1]

**Versions:**

- Web3: 1.0.0-beta.36
- Metamask: 5.3.2
- truffle: 5.0.1

Similar problem is on [the issue of `metamask-extension`](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/6080).

I'd appreciate it if you could help me with some tips. Thank you.

Comment: I have the same issue with beta46 & 47. Have you tried it with those?

Comment: @szerte I haven't. In my case, just beta37 works fine...

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by installing **1.0.0-beta.37**.

Comment: Why would you vote this down? I'm having this exact issue.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error using 1.0.0-beta.37 (sometimes). Meaning, I replicated the application in another directory. Did not copy the node-modules either in server side or the client site (It is MERN with DApp). I regenerated them using >> npm install (to replicate what's happening in heroku)

In the original case, it works (still does). In the new directory (replicated app). .. it throws the error above. I am associating it with npm install doing something differently.

Comment: Are you sure that you installed modules with exact same versions? `npm install` does not install exact versions depending on how you installed modules.
Please check here for [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41003470/npm-install-the-exact-package-version-specified-in-package-json)